# North Stars of each Solar system planet?

Tags: planet, solar-system, celestial-mechanics, navigation

What are the North Stars of each individual body points too?
E.g.
Earth points to Polaris.
Mars points to Deneb/Alpha Cygni.

What about Sun, Mercury, Venus, Moon, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto?

Comment: related in Space Exploration SE: [Is there a Martian “North Star”, usable as Earth's North Star?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2571/12102) and [Does Venus have a north star or south star?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22491/12102) See also [How could one navigate on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2570/12102)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer based on [Is Polaris the north star for all the other planets just like it is for Earth?](https://usm.maine.edu/planet/polaris-north-star-all-other-planets-just-it-earth) and [What star is directly north of the suns north pole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/what-star-is-directly-north-of-the-suns-north-pole)

| Planet | Pole Star |
| --- | --- |
| Sun* | [There is no bright star close to the NCP of the sun](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/what-star-is-directly-north-of-the-suns-north-pole) |
| Mercury | [Omicron Draconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omicron_Draconis) |
| Venus | [42 Draconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_Draconis) |
| Earth | [Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris) |
| Mars | [Sadr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_Cygni) and [Deneb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deneb) |
| Jupiter | [Zeta Draconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_Draconis) |
| Saturn | Saturn's north celestial pole (NCP) is not directed toward any prominent star |
| Uranus | Inclined almost 90 degrees, has a pole oriented toward Orion's "head" region |
| Neptune | [Delta Cygni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Cygni) |
| Pluto* | [Delta Draconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Draconis) |

*-Pluto & Sun as bonus planets